# How to randomly and not repeatedly select elements from an array?

Tags: random, julia

As the title describes, I want to select 2 or 3 elements from an array without replacement.

I know I can do this job with `Base.rand` function and `if` statement together,
but I'm still seeking some more elegant way to do this.

= = = Edit: 2020/01/21 = = =

@Gwang-Jin Kim, @phipsgabler

Thanks for your suggestion, and I make a small test according to your answers.

For the speed issue, maybe `Base.rand` is still a better way, although its time cost fluctuates from `1.3e-7` to `1.4e-7`. But for an elegant way, both `sample` and `shuffle` can be an option.

Is my conclusion right?

```
using Base
using Random
using StatsBase

function _sampling1(M::Int64, N::Int64)
    for i in 1:M
        for j in 1:N
            r1, r2, r3 = Base.rand(1:N, 3)
            while (r1 == r2) | (r2 == r3) | (r1 == r3)
                r2, r3 = Base.rand(1:N, 2)
            end
        end
    end
end

function _sampling2(M::Int64, N::Int64)
    for i in 1:M
        for j in 1:N
            r1, r2, r3 = Random.shuffle(1:N)[1:3]
        end
    end
end

function _sampling3(M::Int64, N::Int64)
    for i in 1:M
        for j in 1:N
            r1, r2, r3 = StatsBase.sample(1:N, 3, replace=false)
        end
    end
end

M = 500
N = 100

time_cost1 = @elapsed _sampling1(M, N)
time_cost2 = @elapsed _sampling2(M, N)
time_cost3 = @elapsed _sampling3(M, N)

println("   rand: $(time_cost1 / (M * N))")
println("shuffle: $(time_cost2 / (M * N))")
println(" sample: $(time_cost3 / (M * N))")

#>>>    rand: 1.3713026e-7
#>>> shuffle: 1.57786382e-6
#>>>  sample: 5.6382496e-7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# thanks for @Bogumił Kamiński for hint that the `sample`
# function actually is from `StatsBase` package

# install `StatsBase` package or `Distributions` package
using Pkg
Pkg.add("StatsBase") # or: Pkg.add("Distributions")

# load it
using StatsBase # or: using Distributions


# the actual code for sampling 3 or 2 elements without replacement
sample(your_array, 3, replace = false) # 3 elements
sample(your_array, 2, replace = false) # 2 elements
```

Comment: Actually `sample` method is defined in StatsBase.jl and only re-exported by Distributions.jl.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a special `shuffle` function from a library, you can use shuffling.  For example, shuffle the array of indices and choose the first 5 of them:

```
using Random

random_indices = shuffle(eachindex(your_array))
your_array[random_indices[1:5]]
```

Fisher-Yates shuffling has linear complexity; in some cases, this has advantages over repeatedly calling `sample` (in terms of practicality or resources).

Instead of the indices, you can also shuffle the array directly (which is probably most cache-friendly).  The most memory efficient way would be to use the in-place `shuffle!` once (e.g. for cross-validation or batching of large data sets).